# Terminal emulator with custom scripts and hotkey support for linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I need a terminal application for linux with support for custom scripts and support to bind this scripts for hotkeys.

For example I login into computers hundreds times a day. I don't want to write login and password, but to press a hotkey. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to automate this process: [`input login, press Enter, input password, press enter, input some command...`]

What application can you suggest to me?

Comment: Why not just use `expect` to automate the logins? Or use `autokey` or `xdotool` scripts to create hotkeys that work with any terminal emulator?

Comment: I feel shame I didn't know about these utilityes. Sounds like that's what I need. I'll check and reply as soon as I can.

Comment: Looks like it's the most suitable application for now. Thanks. A bit buggy application, but fits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitvise Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/download-area), from the maker of PuTTY. Save login credentials as Profiles, and can run scripts on startup from directories on your local machine.

Comment: I need to run scripts, not to use profiles, because I work through ssh from home. I cant access switches directly. There are enormous number of profiles, so it would be inconvenient to have that much. Putty has profiles too, so I wouldn't ask this question, because I know it. And I'm operating linux, so linux applications are preffered.

Answer (score 0):

What is a "commutator"?

To avoid typing usernames and passwords with Putty logins, can you set up public key authentication on the servers and use SSH logins? If you run Pageant then you don't even need to keep re-keying the password for the keyfile but still have it secure.

Here's someone who apparently solved your problem 
http://www.testingminded.com/2009/10/putty-automatic-logon-script-logonputty.html

Comment: Looks like I'm bad in English. By "commutator" I meannt devices like DLink DES-3550, 3220 we use in our network.

Comment: "Ethernet switches" is the more usual way to describe this class of products. The ones that you can SSH into are probably in the sub-group that are usually described as "managed switches".